# ¿Cómo puedo hacer en unity 2021.1 usando Mirror un servidor dedicado que mueva varias partidas de 4 jugadores?

Tags: unity3d

Buenas estoy intentando crear un juego como los comunes, ya sea BattleField o FortNite pero tengo una duda ya que estoy usando Mirror en Unity versión 2022.1 y no he encontrado ninguna referencia de como hacer que los jugadores que se conecten a un Lobby puedan ser 4 y una vez que estos ya estén listos y jugando otros 4 jugadores puedan empezar otra partida y así sucesivamente.
alguien sabe si esto se hace a través de algún código en Mirror, o es algo que se utiliza externamente para reabrir el DedicateServer varias veces.

Comment: Si bien aquí todos somos programadores (o aficcionados), lo cierto es que muy pocos de nosotros tendrán experiencia alguna con Unity. En cambio, una de las mejores cosas que tiene unity desde mi punto de vista es una comunidad **ENORME**, y bastante dispuesta a ayudar a los demás. Aunque tu pregunta encaja con la temática de este sitio y es correcto ponerla aquí, la realidad es que si quieres una respuesta sobre todo a un problema tan concreto, lo mejor es que preguntes en la comunidad de unity y no aquí. Obviamente mejor aún si lo haces en la comunidad en inglés, que es la más grande claro :)

Comment: gracias hermano la verdad es que tengo más de 8 años de experiencia en Unity pero nunca me había tropezado con esta polémica, intentaré en la comunidad de Unity, nuevamente gracias.